# Android Studio - how was this resource file structure trick achieved?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-styles

I was checking out the Google I/O app source code in Android studio, and I came across this IDE layout of the `res/` folder - how was this achieved?

But if I look at my filesystem at the actual file structure, it's the conventional `values/styles.xml`, `values-v17/styles.xml`, `values-v21/styles.xml` arrangement. How can I achieve this in my own app?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OBaBnWr.png]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the "android" project view, where the group together different files in order to minimise file differences vs folder differences.

This is default in Android 0.9.x

[image: ASide 0.9.3]

Answer (score 3):

In 0.8.4, they added [the "Android project view"](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio084released), which is what you're seeing. In [0.8.12](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio0812released), it is the default, but presumably only for new projects, which is why I was not seeing it in my fiddling with 0.8.14 today.

It is also the default in the parallel 0.9.x series in the canary channel.